# Get future bi weekly date

Tags: java, date, math, calendar

My bi weekly payments started on January 1st, 2015 (that is what is in my Date object, it is a Thursday by the way).

How would I find when will I have to pay my first payment in May of 2018? (I do not care about second or third payment in a month).

I would show the work I have done, but I can't begin to think how to think this issue.

Comment: The simplest way is to have a loop that adds 2 weeks at a time until you hit May 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to do it without any loop or iteration, it just requires a little bit of trickery:

```
    LocalDate firstPayment = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    // The first payment in May 2018 must be within the first 14 days of May.
    long weeksAfterFirst
            = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(firstPayment, LocalDate.of(2018, Month.MAY, 14));
    // We need an even number of weeks
    if (weeksAfterFirst % 2 != 0) {
        weeksAfterFirst--;
    }
    LocalDate firstInMay = firstPayment.plusWeeks(weeksAfterFirst);
    System.out.println(firstInMay);
```

This prints

> 2018-05-03

For how to embark on such a task, one first step is to study the date and time library to learn about the possibilities. **Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: FYI, for a bit more type-safety, the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project offers the [`Weeks`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Weeks.html) class with methods such as [`Weeks.between`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Weeks.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) and `Weeks::plus`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a datetime object, then keep adding weeks (2*7 days) until the month and year are correct.

Comment: That is one way to solve it, however it sounds like a very slow way to solve it. Is there no faster way?

Comment: You could calculate the number of days between the two dates, then find the remainder with respect to 14, then the final answer would be 14-x. 

But on the other hand, the loop method takes milliseconds, and avoiding off-by-one errors could take you an entire minute. Maybe two!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `Stream<LocalDate>` if I were you:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2015, 1, 1);

System.out.println(Stream.iterate(start, d -> d.plusWeeks(2))
                         .filter(d -> d.getMonth() == Month.MAY && d.getYear() == 2018)
                         .findFirst()
                         .get());
```

Output:

```
2018-05-03
```

I forgot the proper way to get an element from an infinite stream, but this is one method.